# Why does bind_result come before execute

Tags: php

So i am watching this [tutorial](https://youtu.be/P9XVX9OqQOc?t=451) and as you can see the guy put execute after bind_result. Shouldn't execute come before bind_result?

Answer (score 1):

It seems, you're correct.

As [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php) says:

> **Note:**
>
> **Note that all columns must be bound after mysqli_stmt_execute() and prior to calling mysqli_stmt_fetch()**. Depending on column types bound variables can silently change to the corresponding PHP type.
>
> A column can be bound or rebound at any time, even after a result set has been partially retrieved. The new binding takes effect the next time mysqli_stmt_fetch() is called.